# Selecting a RANDOM key and then breaking out of Iterator / loop in HashMap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, iteration, break

I'm trying to loop through a HashMap such that it should select any random KEY and  if that KEY is found it should break out of the loop and select the value corresponding to that KEY.

But somehow this code is not working and it is selecting only a particular value. Please note that it has all the values and keys for which I have coded the IF statement below.

Below is my code

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Set<String>>> it = arg0.getSubstylearea().entrySet().iterator();

    A: while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>) it.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Set<String> temp = arg0.getSubstylearea().get(key);

        if (key.equals("Eyes")) {
            flatont.setStylearea1(key);
            System.out.println("This Doesnt Print");
            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);

            }
            break A;
        } else if (key.equals("Face")) {

            flatont.setStylearea1(key);

            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
            }
            break A;
        } else if (key.equals("Lips")) {

            flatont.setStylearea1(key);

            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
            }
            break A;
        } 
}
```

Please help me with how to achieve this

Comment: What happens if you remove `break` statements? or use `continue` instead?

Comment: If i use continue , as suggested in the answer below , it will still itreate through the loop and I might end up with unwanted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're after, but try this:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = arg0.getSubstylearea()
    int index = new Random().nextInt(map.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (i++ < index) {
            continue;
        }
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Set<String> temp = arg0.getSubstylearea().get(key);

        if (key.equals("Eyes")) {
            flatont.setStylearea1(key);
            System.out.println("This Doesnt Print");
            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);

            }
        } else if (key.equals("Face")) {

            flatont.setStylearea1(key);

            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
            }
        } else if (key.equals("Lips")) {

            flatont.setStylearea1(key);

            for (String s : temp) {

                flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
            }
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply , what you have thought exactly that im trying to achieve , ie select a random key and then based on that key select its corresponding value. Also what should I do when the map is empty , as its exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive

Comment: If the map is empty (or null) you should skip the code completely. Just return; the method or wrap everything in an if-block

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple `continue`:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>) it.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Set<String> temp = arg0.getSubstylearea().get(key);

    if (key.equals("Eyes")) {
        flatont.setStylearea1(key);
        System.out.println("This Doesnt Print");
        for (String s : temp) {

            flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);

        }
        continue;
    } else if (key.equals("Face")) {

        flatont.setStylearea1(key);

        for (String s : temp) {

            flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
        }
        continue;
    } else if (key.equals("Lips")) {

        flatont.setStylearea1(key);

        for (String s : temp) {

            flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);
        }
        continue;
    } 
}
```

This woud still iterate over keys even if one of the named keys has been found. Otherwise, make a simple `break`:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>) it.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Set<String> temp = arg0.getSubstylearea().get(key);

    if (key.equals("Eyes")) {
        flatont.setStylearea1(key);
        System.out.println("This Doesnt Print");
        for (String s : temp) {

            flatont.setStylesubarea1(s);

        }
        break;
    } else if ... etc
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply , break isnt working correctly as I'm getting values only for Hydration !

Comment: @RahulKoshaley ... "Hydration"... isn't in your source ? And it's either continue or break. Your `break A` is equivalent to `continue`.

Comment: Yes its in my source , but its only  selecting Hydration , and not the other values.